# Is it wise to delete post revisions and autosaves from database?

Tags: database, revisions, autosave

I'm just wondering is it wise to delete all post revisions and autosaves from database every once in a while?
I mean they take a lot of database space and apparently have no use after the post has been published.

Comment: No use is not absolutely true. When you search my answer, then there's one where we did something like liveediting Spreadsheets using the Post Revisions. Currently I'm also thinking about another implementation, where they get used to save edits-diffs like here on SE/SO using `wp_text_diff()`.

Comment: Well in some rare cases what you said might be true, but in a usual Wordpress installation I don't think they're of much use.

Comment: *close voted* as _non constructive_.

Comment: Can I ask why? I have a question and it's not off-topic and it also is constructive **for me**.

Comment: Two reasons: First, this site, it's questions & answers are _not only for you_, but for later readers also. Second, your answer will only summon _opinions_ and not definitive answers. Your question title already asks "Is it wise(...)?". So the answers will be "in my opinion, I think, in that use case or this sceanrio", etc. That's what the blog will be for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your workflow. If you have no use for the post revisions and autosaves then disable them in wp-config and WordPress will clean them up on its own. You may also prefer to limit how many you keep at once.

Also the space they take up is unlikely to be of a great impact itself unless you're running on a tiny tiny server

Don't go deleting them manually through the database.