# How to delete old posts' edits to save space?

Tags: posts, customization

I need to delete old edits and autosave, they have grown overtime, and are not needed anymore, seeing this post:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67228/27148

it states:

> If you have no use for the post revisions and autosaves then disable them in wp-config and WordPress will clean them up on its own

but I can't find exactly where to edit.

using wordpress 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [edit `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions).

To set posts to retain a set number of revisions:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3);
```

To disable post revisions completely:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );
```

Answer (score 3):

As i'm new to wordpress.stackexchange.com, i cannot comment (silly idea)

To further extend Chip's answer.

You can also delete all revisions from the database which appear before X date to remove old revisions that are not needed, whilst keeping newer revisions to what ever limit you want.  simply run the query:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'revision' AND `post_date` < '2012-06-02 20:41:00';
```

replacing the date with your date.  this way you can clear revisions for your really old posts, but keep revisions for your newer posts

Please don't down vote, I would have commented :)