# How safe is it to delete old posts edits to save database space?

Tags: posts, database, customization

After this question:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93902/27148

There is an answer that suggests deleting past edits directly from database, which would be nice, because I could create queries to delete specific edits only.

But, Is this safe? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revisional feature of WordPress is only for users. That means, that if you don't need them old revisions, you can safely delete them. The system actually doesn't care.